# React-Bootstrap background Color

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm trying to change the background color of my React-Bootstrap Button.

I did this

`const btn ={backgroundColor: '#F16E10'};
<Button bsStyle="" bsClass="btn" bsSize="large" onClick={this.handleEvent}>Something</Button>`

But it's not working, who can I change this background color ?

Thanks,

Comment: By using a css file with ".btn" I can change the background color off all my react bootstrap button (default value of bsClass).But if I try to put bsClass="btn2" to specify the color for just one button, I loose the bootstrap style. Can I change this bsClass default value without loosing the bootstrap style ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to your code, you try to apply the class .btn but you just declared a const btn. Do you expect your button to have the backgrouncolor to #F16E10?

Did you try to add a prop style? like this

```
<Button bsStyle="" style={btn} bsClass="btn" bsSize="large">Something</Button>
```

Comment: Thanks ! I didn't know that you can use prop style in a React Bootstrap

Comment: Yes usually you can set style on Component but, react bootstrap make it support